# "syntax error near unexpected token `('" error with process substitution

Tags: bash, syntax

I get a problem when executing this command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/comm -13 < (sort test.tsv) < (sort test_2.tsv)
```

> ```
> Error: d_t.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> d_t.sh: line 4: `sudo /usr/bin/comm -13 < (sort test.tsv) < (sort test_2.tsv)'
> ```

Comment: Remove the space between `<` and `(`.

Comment: Retagged: This is specific to [tag:bash] and has nothing specifically with [tag:centos] to do.

Comment: It shouldn't be tagged bash at all if the OP is using `sh` to run the script (as their self-answer implies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `sudo`:

- `sudo sort test.tsv > text1.tsv`
- `sudo sort test2.tsv > text2.tsv`
- `sudo comm -13 text1.tsv text2.tsv`

Answer (score 3):

Proper process substitution syntax would be:

```
sudo /usr/bin/comm -13 <(sort test.tsv) <(sort test_2.tsv)
```

There is no space between the the "<" or ">" and the parentheses.

See the bash hackers wiki page on [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).

Also note that process substitution is not supported by POSIX sh.

Comment: We generally hesitate to link to the ABS because it is, ahem, variable quality. But the answer is good.

Comment: Could I suggest that you modify the link to use a better-reputed reference? http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst, f/e

Answer (score 1):

You can use one by one command

- `sort test.tsv > text1.tsv sort test2.tsv > text2.tsv comm -13 text1.tsv text2.tsv`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use one by one command

```
sort test.tsv > text1.tsv 
sort test2.tsv > text2.tsv
comm -13 text1.tsv text2.tsv
```